# how to use"this mathematic expression?

Tags: mathematics

I know the sentence below is incorrect , but would you please correct me? By this I mean the expression is not workable for the formula, so we must  use it in another equations, not formula.

> **'This algebraic expression above is not satisfy for the following**
>   **formula.'**

Many thanks all

Comment: You've got two answers, but by now you ought to know that if we are looking for error(s) in a sentence you should point us towards your major suspect(s) and tell us your reasons for suspicion. It's not too much to ask really :-) just a line or two about your own thoughts.

Answer (score 3):

The big problem is that you're trying to use "is" (the "being" verb) to attribute something with a verb instead of an adjective. You can use "does," as in @TzD's example, to make that connection appropriately, or you can change "satisfy" to an adjective:

> 'This algebraic expression above is not satisfactory for the following formula.'

"This algebraic expression above" is also close, but still incorrect. You can say "the above algebraic expression" or "the algebraic expression above." You could also just say "this algebraic expression" without "above" if you are confident the reader will know which expression you are talking about.

Comment: _'The algebraic expression above is not satisfactory for the following formula.'_  I agree that this is grammatically correct, and has a useful meaning.  To my ear, the meaning it carries is less precise than  _"The algebraic expression does not satisfy the following formula._  The latter (with _satisfy_ as a verb) means specifically that substituting the expression into the formula above will not result in a true statement.  e.g.  `X=Sqrt(5)`  _does not satisfy the formula_ `2x = 5`  The adjective, _satisfactory,_ may just mean that you don't like the result.

Comment: "Fulfilling all demands or requirements," as in the definition at dictionary.reference.com, is generally the definition I use for "satisfactory." Therefore it's an adjective that doesn't describe whether or not I like it; instead it describes whether or not the thing in question does what it's supposed to do. I try to use words more precisely than most, though.

Comment: _"All demands or requirements"_ - to me this would include demands and requirements outside of mathematical constraints.  The algebraic expression in might result in a valid mathematical statement that indicates your business will be bankrupt or your dog will die.  To me, those would be "unsatisfactory" results, even if the equation has been satisfied. Using words precisely is tricky in math.  Just because I have grouped three things does not mean I have a group, just as satisfying an equation does not mean I will find it satisfactory.  (Or even that _I_ will be satisfied.)

Answer (score 1):

> **'This algebraic expression above is not satisfy for the following formula.'**

You can write it like this:-

> The algebraic expression above does not satisfy the following formula.

or

> The above algebraic expression does not satisfy the following formula.

The problem of the sentence I think the be verb 'is'.

Comment: Thanks. However, I cannot observe any example by googling the examples you have provided or even mine.

Comment: I basically agree with TzD's answer, though I prefer _"The algebraic expression above does not satisfy the following equation"_  You may not find the exact language of either mine or his by googling, because they are wordy, specific phrases.  Try googling "satisfies the formula" or "satisfies the equation:"  https://www.google.com/search?q=satisfies+the+equation"  You will get millions of hits.  The opposite of _"satisfies"_ is _"does not satisfy,"_ which matches what @TzD proposed.